# mvc reach editorfor from controller by its name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, editorformodel

hello everyone I am trying to reach EditorFor by giving a name to it. I gave a name like this

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.name,new {name = "sizeName"})
```

and I am trying to get it from controller

```
public ActionResult EditSize(int id,string sizeName)
    {
        Repository<SizeList> _rs = new Repository<SizeList>();
        SizeList _sizeList = _rs.Find(a => a.id == id);

        _sizeList.name = sizeName;
        _rs.Save();

        return RedirectToAction("Size");
    }
```

but it didnt get the sizeName what can I do for this thank you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because with `@Html.EditorFor()` you already set name by passing model to this helper. This helper generate HTML attribute with `name="name"`.

So, in your controller method you should have:

```
public ActionResult EditSize(string name,int id)
    {
        Repository<SizeList> _rs = new Repository<SizeList>();
        SizeList _sizeList = _rs.Find(a => a.id == id);

        _sizeList.name = name;
        _rs.Save();

        return RedirectToAction("Size");
    }
```

and your helper should looks like:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a model object, a TempData, a ViewBag or a ViewData to save that object value, and then you can use that to set name of your html element.

Controller example:

```
public ActionResult EditSize(int id,string sizeName)
    {
        Repository<SizeList> _rs = new Repository<SizeList>();
        SizeList _sizeList = _rs.Find(a => a.id == id);

        TempData["sizeName"] = sizeName;
        //or ViewBag.sizeName = sizeName;
        //or ViewData["sizeName"] = sizeName;

        _sizeList.name = sizeName;
        _rs.Save();

        return RedirectToAction("Size");
    }
```

HTML examples:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.name,new {Name = TempData.Peek("sizeName") })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.name,new {Name = ViewData["sizeName"] })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.name,new {Name = ViewBag.sizeName })
```

NOTES:

You can only specify the name in this way if the first letter is **uppercase** (not 'name' but 'Name').

If you want to POST the field value to that specific model property you don't need to specify the element name, because the name is set automatically with the model property name.